# Generating a short preview of a .webm movie

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to improve my website so I would like to replace the existing .jpg thumbnails with a live preview like in youtube.After hovering over the movie, a short video showing what's going on in the movie is shown. Do you have any idea or tip on how I can achieve this effect with ffmpeg?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Did you attempt to take a clip with ffmpeg? What was the result?

Answer (score 0):

You can swap the thumbnail for each video with a gif on hover, you can do this easily with ffmpeg -i video.webm output.gif -hide_banner